# laravel5.4 validate can not show $errors

Tags: forms, laravel, validation

I use validate to confirm register form .
`$message = array('required' => 'you can not');

```
    $datavalidate = array(
        'phone' =>$request->input('phone')
    );
    $rules = array(
        'phone' =>'required'
    );

    $validator = Validator::make($datavalidate,$rules,$message);
    if($validator->fails())
    {
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator);

    }

    $this->validate($request,[
        'phone' => 'required',
        'confirmCode' => 'required'
    ]);`
```

two way both can not get $errors.
 I can sure this validate worked.throw a exception,because after validate method ,all code not excuse.
 But I can get $errors,maybe direct wrong url?
this is include in register web.
`

```
    <ul>
        <li>hello</li>
        @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{$error}}</li>
            @endforeach
    </ul>
{{var_dump($errors)}}
```

this list can not show any $error.Is there not direct last url .
UPDATE:this is form.

```
            <form class="form-horizontal" action="{{route('confirmRegister')}}"method="post" onsubmit="return postForm()">

            {{csrf_field()}}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="mobileNum" class="col-xs-3 control-label text-center">手机号</label>
                <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" id="mobileNum" placeholder="手机号码">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">

                <label for="passWord" class="col-xs-3 text-center">密码</label>
                <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="passWord" placeholder="密码">
                    <input type="hidden" id="sendPassWord" name="passWord">
                    <input type="hidden" id="openId" name="openId">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">

                <label for="confirmPassWord" class="col-xs-3 text-center">确认密码</label>
                <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <input type="password" name="confirmPassWord" class="form-control" id="confirmPassWord" placeholder="确认密码">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="confirm" class="col-xs-3 text-center">验证码</label>
                <div class="col-xs-5">
                    <input type="text" name="confirmCode" class="form-control" id="confirm" placeholder="短信验证码">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-block" id="getConfirm">获取验证码</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-8" role="alert" style="display: none" id="codeError">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <strong>错误!</strong> 获取验证码失败！
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-8">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="register">注册</button>
                </div>
            </div>





        </form>
```

UPDATE:

```
        function postForm() {

        var passWord = md5( $('#passWord').val() );
        $('#sendPassWord').val(passWord);

        $('#openId').val("{{$openId}}");


        return true;


    }
```

Comment: Please share the HTML of the form that you are submitting.

Comment: @haakym,see update.

Comment: Are you using ajax to submit the form because I can see this in your form html code: `onsubmit="return postForm()"`

Comment: @haakym. I do not use ajax submit.I don't want post the real password to server,need post after md5,so I recode a function for submit.See my update.

Comment: If you immediately `dd(request())` in the controller you are posting to, what result do you see? Is it what you expect? I want to check the request is coming through properly.

Comment: @haakym.yes,dd(request()).I can see what I post to server .

Comment: @haakym.Maybe the reason was middleware web?I declare route in web.php. will that use web middleware,right?

Comment: @haakym.Finally,I find the reason.my Controller when receive form post,the Controller will request another server and return a url ,then,Controller redirect to this url ,if I do not request another server,I can show the errors.

Comment: Great! Glad you fixed it. You can always answer your own question by the way.

Answer (score 0):

```
    phone<input type="text" name="phone" >
    <span class="error">{{$errors->first('phone')}}</span>

    confirmCode<input type="text" name="confirmCode">
    <span class="error">{{$errors->first('confirmCode')}}</span>
```

controller codes

```
     $rules = ['phone' => 'required',
            'confirmCode' => 'required',

        ];
        $message = [
            'phone.required' => 'enter your phone number',
            'confirmCode.required' => 'confirm your code

        ];
        $validator = validator::make($request->input(), $rules, $message);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return back()
                ->WithErrors($validator)
                ->WithInput();
}else{    write your codes here
```

try this one. set your rules and message in this way

Comment: add error class in your blade page . I have added blade page in my answer. go through it. it may helps you